# 1 factor, 1 covariate, single control group. Is ANCOVA possible?

Tags: ancova, control-group

Let's say in our experiment we have three drugs (factor), each in 3 doses (covariate), with a separate group of subjects assigned to every drug-dose combination, and a single control group (no drug). **Can I run an omnibus test, say ANCOVA, that includes the control group? If so, what group layout should I use?** First thought, if I include the control group as a zero-dosage group for every drug, that would be an independence issue.

Comment: What’s the independence issue?

Comment: If I use same set of data for zero dose groups, they will clearly not be independent, unlike for other dosages. That would also reduce between-group variance, introduce heteroscedasticity and affect within-group variance. Am I not right?